# How to get the PIDL of any folder to use in RegisterChangeNotify

Tags: c#, windows, shell

I want to watch a folder (for example 'c:\test') for changes.
I found the following piece of code but I don't know how to get to the FolderPIDL for any given folder.

```
    public ulong RegisterChangeNotify(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr FolderPIDL, bool Recursively)
    {
        if(notifyid != 0) return(0);
        SHChangeNotifyEntry changeentry = new SHChangeNotifyEntry();
        changeentry.pIdl = FolderPIDL;
        changeentry.Recursively = Recursively;
        notifyid = SHChangeNotifyRegister(
            hWnd,
            SHCNF.SHCNF_TYPE | SHCNF.SHCNF_IDLIST,
            SHCNE.SHCNE_ALLEVENTS | SHCNE.SHCNE_INTERRUPT,
            WM_SHNOTIFY,
            1,
            ref changeentry);
        return(notifyid);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a PIDL from a path with the [ILCreateFromPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378420.aspx) method (for a real file/folder path):

```
IntPtr pidl = ILCreateFromPath(@"c:\path\file.ext");
if (pidl != IntPtr.Zero)
try
{
    // do something
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pidl);
}
```